# jQuery Trying to open modal box, it closes in a fraction of a second

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a modal box following this tutorial: 
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp with jQuery. Here's what I got:

```js
$(function() {

  var $openMacros = $(".profile-form #open-macros");
  var $macrosModal = $(".profile-form .modal-macros");
  var $closeMacros = $macrosModal.find("#close-macros");

  $openMacros.click(function() {
    $macrosModal.show();
    event.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

```css
.modal-macros {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-form">
  <a href="#edit_macros" class="button-green button macros-button" id="open-macros">Set macros</a>
  <div class="modal-macros">Modal</div>
</div>
```

What happens is my modal box opens for a fraction of a second and then closes immediately. I tried using return false or preventDefault inside of my onclick method and it indeed works, but after I close the modal box I can't open it again. Anyone can help?

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Seems like something is missing from your code, I don't see it closing immediately...

Comment: The code in question is made into a snippet. Can you try reproducing the issue in snippet if possible. Also include `event` as a parameter on click function. Otherwise there is a chance that `window.event` will be used instead. `$openMacros.click(function(event) {`. Such behaviour as yours is usually seen when page reloads, so test it by removing the `href` in open button completely.

Comment: I usually set css properties to modal. For example, here you have .modal-macros { display: none;} . To make it appear, i use document.getElementsByClassName("modal-macros")[0].style.display = "block";